# Remove item click event handler for single items in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, event-handling, windows-store-apps, itemssource

In my Windows Store app I use a `GridView` with an `ItemClick` event handler:

```
<GridView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
  SelectionMode="None"
  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
  ItemClick="ClickOnItem">
</GridView>
```

The items are bound to the `GridView` with `ItemsSource`. Is there the possibility to remove the click event for single items which have been bound to the GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how suitable this is for your scenario, but one way to do this is to just ignore the click event based on the item:

```
void ClickOnItem(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (SampleDataItem)e.ClickedItem;

    // ignore one specific item - here we use UniqueId, but it could be
    // any attribute...
    if (string.Compare(item.UniqueId, "Group-1-Item-1") == 0)
        return;

    // normal processing here...
    ...
 }
```

---

**Update** - to add a click event programmatically, you have to name your grid (`x:Name` line):

```
<GridView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="myGridView"
    SelectionMode="None"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="ClickOnItem">
</GridView>
```

and then in the code behind, add the handler in the constructor of the page:

```
public PageConstructor()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    myGridView.ItemClick += ClickOnItem;
}
```

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer - you can programmatically add the click handler to the grid itself, which will then handle the click events for each item. See my **Update** above.